# MySQL limit rows per particular column values

Tags: mysql, limit

I have a query result like this img:

[image]

I want to limit result by column:ID values because the number of rows is unpredictable.(in this example, i want top two ID records. but you can see ID=12 has 5 rows and ID=7 has 6 rows.)
I can't group by ID because each row has special values.
Thank you :)

Comment: E.g. (and crudely): `SELECT x.* FROM my_table x JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM  my_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 2) y ON y.id = x.id;`

Comment: @Strawberry it seems true but not efficient. because the table is result of a heavy query and it is already expensive. is n't any SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, a solution using variables would be more efficient. But if you want a better answer (from me), then you need to ask a better question. ;-) I note that the PRIMARY KEY is formed on (id,user_id,field_name). This is perfectly reasonable - but it makes the problem a little harder to comprehend (for those of us whose Arabic is not so great).

Comment: @Strawberry this not Arabic! It's Persian :)  in this query result, id refers to a product. each product has some fields (counts of fields is unpredictable). But i don't want all product. i just want a limit numbers with all related fields.

Comment: See. Mine is even worse than I thought!